# building for iOS Simulator, but linking in .tbd built for macOS/Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, tuist

In my iOS project, when I build my app from the command line with the following command :

```
xcodebuild -project Project.xcodeproj -scheme Scheme -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14 Pro'
```

I get the following error :

```
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in .tbd built for macOS/Mac Catalyst, file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd' for architecture x86_64
```

There is no mention of Mac Catalyst in the build settings so I don't know where that comes from. Any ideas ?